# Focus on form field that does not appear for 800ms

Tags: slider, focus, onload

I have a form in a slider, and I want the courser to focus on the first field, but the form does not appear for 800ms, so I'm having trouble with the onload statements. See: retailcapital.com, want the courser to be in the "your name" field on load.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Try JQuery `$(document).ready()` instead of window onload.

Documentation: http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Example:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#calc_name').focus();
});
```

Comment: Still does not do it??

Comment: Will any of this help?

Comment: revapi1.bind("revolution.slide.onloaded",function (e) {
 //alert("slider loaded");
});
  
revapi1.bind("revolution.slide.onchange",function (e,data) {
 //alert("slide changed to: "+data.slideIndex);
});

revapi1.bind("revolution.slide.onpause",function (e,data) {
 //alert("timer paused");
});

revapi1.bind("revolution.slide.onresume",function (e,data) {
 //alert("timer resume");
});

revapi1.bind("revolution.slide.onvideoplay",function (e,data) {
 //alert("video play");
});

revapi1.bind("revolution.slide.onvideostop",function (e,data) {
 //alert("video stopped");
});